# SAP Web Intelligence translation of formulas

Tags: business-intelligence, business-objects, webi

How can I translate SAP Web Intelligence (WebI) formulas between English and another language?

For example, on the Italian version of WebI I have to write `Somma([Profit])`, instead of `Sum([Profit])`. Is there a way to find the equivalence between the two languages or a tool to translate it (something like the [Excel translator tool](https://it.excel-translator.de/translator/))?

Comment: Unlikely that such automatic tool exists

Comment: Would it work to change your computer's regional settings back and forth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a Python script and some hands-on SAP Business Objects documentation, **I made a table to translate between WEBI functions across English, German, and Italian.**

It is not a translator, but hope could help people working with different instances of SAP BO in different languages.
**Please feel free to edit my post (if you have the privileges to do it) or post in the comments any mistake or void in the table.**

```
+-----------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|              English              |                      German                      |                               Italian                                |
+-----------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| In                                | In                                               | In                                                                   |
| ForEach                           | FürJeden                                         | PerOgni                                                              |
| ForAll                            | FürAlle                                          | PerTutto                                                             |
| If...Then...Else                  | Wenn...Dann...Sonst                              | Se...Quindi...Altrimenti                                             |
| If                                | Wenn                                             | Se                                                                   |
| LineNumber                        | ZeileNummer                                      | NumeroRiga                                                           |
| NameOf                            | NameVon                                          | NomeDi                                                               |
| NoFilter                          | KeinFilter                                       | NessunFiltro                                                         |
| Page                              | Seite                                            | Pagina                                                               |
| Previous                          | Vorherige                                        | Precedente                                                           |
| RefValue                          | RefWert                                          | ValoreRif                                                            |
| ColumnNumber                      | SpalteNummer                                     | NumeroColonna                                                        |
| RelativeValue                     | RelativerWert                                    | ValoreRelativo                                                       |
| ReportName                        | Berichtsname                                     | NomeReport                                                           |
| RowIndex                          | ZeilenIndex                                      | IndiceRighe                                                          |
| Comment                           | Kommentar                                        | Commento                                                             |
| ForceMerge                        | ZusammenführungErzwingen                         | ForzaUnione                                                          |
| GetContentLocale                  | InhaltsgebietsschemaAbrufen                      | OttieniImpostazioniInternazionaliContenuto                           |
| GetDominantPreferredViewingLocale | DominantesBevorzugtesAnzeigegebietsschemaAbrufen | OttieniImpostazioniInternazionaliDiVisualizzazionePreferiteDominanti |
| GetLocale                         | GebietsschemaAbrufen                             | GetLocale                                                            |
| GetLocalized                      | LokalisierteAbrufen                              | OttieneLocalizzato                                                   |
| Aggregate                         | Aggregation                                      | Aggregato                                                            |
| Min                               | Min                                              | Min                                                                  |
| Mode                              | Modus                                            | Modo                                                                 |
| Percentage                        | Prozent                                          | Percentuale                                                          |
| Percentile                        | Perzentil                                        | Percentile                                                           |
| Product                           | Produkt                                          |                                                                      |
| RunningAverage                    | LaufenderDurchschnitt                            | MediaCumulata                                                        |
| RunningCount                      | LaufendeAnzahl                                   | ConteggioCumulato                                                    |
| RunningMax                        | LaufendesMaximum                                 | MaxCumulato                                                          |
| RunningMin                        | LaufendesMinimum                                 | MinCumulato                                                          |
| RunningProduct                    | LaufendesProdukt                                 | ProdottoCumulato                                                     |
| RunningSum                        | LaufendeSumme                                    | SommaCumulata                                                        |
| StdDev                            | StdAbw                                           | DeviazioneStandard                                                   |
| StdDevP                           | StAbwP                                           | DeviazioneStandardPop                                                |
| Sum                               | Summe                                            | Somma                                                                |
| Var                               | Var                                              | Varianza                                                             |
| VarP                              | VarianzP                                         | VarianzaPop                                                          |
| Average                           | Durchschnitt                                     | Media                                                                |
| Count                             | Anzahl                                           | Conteggio                                                            |
| First                             | Erste                                            | Primo                                                                |
| Interpolation                     | Interpolation                                    | Interpolazione                                                       |
| Last                              | Letzte                                           | Ultimo                                                               |
| Max                               | Max                                              | Max                                                                  |
| Median                            | Median                                           | Mediana                                                              |
| Asc                               | Asc                                              | Asc                                                                  |
| LeftPad                           | AuffüllenLinks                                   | RiempiSpaziASinistra                                                 |
| LeftTrim                          | LöschLeerLinks                                   | EliminaSpaziASinistra                                                |
| Length                            | Länge                                            | Lunghezza                                                            |
| Lower                             | KleinAlleBuchst                                  | Minuscole                                                            |
| Match                             | Vergleich                                        | Confronta                                                            |
| Pos                               | Pos                                              | Pos                                                                  |
| Replace                           | Ersetzen                                         | Sostituisci                                                          |
| Right                             | Rechts                                           | Destra                                                               |
| RightPad                          | AuffüllenRechts                                  | RiempiSpaziADestra                                                   |
| RightTrim                         | LöschLeerRechts                                  | EliminaSpaziADestra                                                  |
| Char                              | Zeich                                            | Car                                                                  |
| Substr                            | Teilzeichenfolge                                 | Sottostringa                                                         |
| Trim                              | Löschen                                          | EliminaSpazi                                                         |
| Upper                             | GroßAlleBuchst                                   | Maiuscole                                                            |
| UrlEncode                         | URLKodierung                                     | CodificaURL                                                          |
| WordCap                           | GroßAlleWörter                                   | TuttoMaiuscole                                                       |
| Concatenation                     | Verkettung                                       | Concatenamento                                                       |
| Fill                              | Füllen                                           | Ricopia                                                              |
| FormatDate                        | FormatDatum                                      | FormatoData                                                          |
| FormatNumber                      | FormatZahl                                       | FormatoNumero                                                        |
| HTMLEncode                        | HTMLEncode                                       | CodificaHTML                                                         |
| InitCap                           | GroßAnfang                                       | Maiuscola                                                            |
| Left                              | Links                                            | Sinistra                                                             |
| CurrentDate                       | AktuellesDatum                                   | DataCorrente                                                         |
| Month                             | Monat                                            | Mese                                                                 |
| MonthNumberOfYear                 | NummerMonatDesJahres                             | NumeroMeseAnno                                                       |
| MonthsBetween                     | MonateZwischen                                   | MesiTra                                                              |
| Quarter                           | Quartal                                          | Trimestre                                                            |
| RelativeDate                      | DatumRelativ                                     | DataRelativa                                                         |
| TimeDim                           | ZeitDim                                          | DimensioneOra                                                        |
| ToDate                            | InDatum                                          | InData                                                               |
| Week                              | Woche                                            | Settimana                                                            |
| Year                              | Jahr                                             | Anno                                                                 |
| CurrentTime                       | AktuelleUhrzeit                                  | OraCorrente                                                          |
| DayName                           | NameDesTages                                     | NomeGiorno                                                           |
| DayNumberOfMonth                  | NummerTagDesMonats                               | NumeroGiornoDelMese                                                  |
| DayNumberOfWeek                   | NummerTagDerWoche                                | NumeroGiornoDellaSettimana                                           |
| DayNumberOfYear                   | NummerTagDesJahres                               | NumeroGiornoAnno                                                     |
| DaysBetween                       | TageZwischen                                     | GiorniTra                                                            |
| LastDayOfMonth                    | LetzterTagDesMonats                              | UltimoGiornoDelMese                                                  |
| LastDayOfWeek                     | LetzterTagDerWoche                               | UltimoGiornoDellaSettimana                                           |
| Connection                        | Verbindung                                       | Connessione                                                          |
| LastExecutionTime                 | UhrzeitLetzteAusführung                          | OraUltimaEsecuzione                                                  |
| NumberOfDataProviders             | AnzahlDatenprovider                              | NumeroFornitoreDati                                                  |
| NumberOfRows                      | AnzahlZeilen                                     | NumeroRighe                                                          |
| RefValueUserReponse               | ReferenzwertAntwortBenutzer                      | ValoreRifRispostaUtente                                              |
| ServerValue                       | Serverwert                                       | ValoreServer                                                         |
| UniverseName                      | Universumsname                                   | NomeUniverso                                                         |
| UserResponse                      | AntwortBenutzer                                  | RispostaUtente                                                       |
| DataProvider                      | Datenprovider                                    | FornitoreDiDati                                                      |
| DataProviderKeyDate               | DatenproviderSchlüsseldatum                      | DataPrincipaleFornitoreDiDati                                        |
| DataProviderKeyDateCaption        | DatenproviderSchlüsseldatumBeschriftung          | DidascaliaDataPrincipaleFornitoreDiDati                              |
| DataProviderSQL                   | DatenproviderSQL                                 | FornitoreDiDatiSQL                                                   |
| DataProviderType                  | DatenproviderTyp                                 | TipoFornitoreDiDati                                                  |
| IsPromptAnswered                  | WurdeEingabeaufforderungBeantwortet              | ÈPromptConRisposta                                                   |
| LastExecutionDate                 | DatumLetzteAusführung                            | DataUltimaEsecuzione                                                 |
| LastExecutionDuration             | DauerLetzteAusführung                            | DurataUltimaEsecuzione                                               |
| PromptSummary                     | Eingabeaufforderungszusammenfassung              | RiepilogoPrompt                                                      |
| QuerySummary                      | Abfragezusammenfassung                           | RiepilogoQuery                                                       |
| ReportFilter                      | BerichtFilter                                    | FiltroReport                                                         |
| ReportFilterSummary               | Berichtfilterzusammenfassung                     | RiepilogoFiltroReport                                                |
| DocumentCreationDate              | DokumenterstellungDatum                          | DataCreazioneDocumento                                               |
| DocumentDate                      | DokumentDatum                                    | DataDocumento                                                        |
| DocumentName                      | DokumentName                                     | NomeDocumento                                                        |
| DocumentPartiallyRefreshed        | DokumentTeilRegeneriert                          | DocumentoParzialmenteAggiornato                                      |
| DocumentTime                      | DokumentUhrzeit                                  | OraDocumento                                                         |
| DrillFilters                      | DrillFilter                                      | FiltriDrill                                                          |
| Even                              | Gerade                                           | Pari                                                                 |
| IsDate                            | IstDatum                                         | ÈData                                                                |
| IsError                           | IstFehler                                        | ÈErrore                                                              |
| IsLogical                         | IstBoolesch                                      | ÈLogico                                                              |
| IsNull                            | IstNull                                          | ÈNull                                                                |
| IsNumber                          | IstZahl                                          | ÈNumero                                                              |
| IsString                          | IstZeichenfolge                                  | ÈStringa                                                             |
| IsTime                            | IstUhrzeit                                       | ÈOra                                                                 |
| Odd                               | Ungerade                                         | Dispari                                                              |
| Abs                               | Abs                                              | Ass                                                                  |
| Floor                             | AnzahlDatenprovider                              | InteroInf                                                            |
| Ln                                | Ln                                               | Ln                                                                   |
| Log                               | Log                                              | Log                                                                  |
| Mod                               | AnzahlDatenprovider                              | Resto                                                                |
| Power                             | Potenz                                           | Potenza                                                              |
| Rank                              | Rang                                             | Classifica                                                           |
| Round                             | Runden                                           | Arrot                                                                |
| Sign                              | Zeichen                                          | Segno                                                                |
| Sin                               | Sin                                              | Sen                                                                  |
| Ceil                              | Obergrenze                                       | InteroSup                                                            |
| Sqrt                              | Quadratwurzel                                    | RadQ                                                                 |
| ToDecimal                         | ToDecimal                                        | ToDecimal                                                            |
| ToNumber                          | InZahl                                           | InNumero                                                             |
| Truncate                          | Abschneiden                                      | Tronca                                                               |
| Cos                               | Cos                                              | Cos                                                                  |
| EuroConvertFrom                   | AusEuroKonvertieren                              | EuroConvertiDa                                                       |
| EuroConvertTo                     | InEuroKonvertieren                               | EuroConvertiIn                                                       |
| EuroFromRoundError                | AusEuroRundungsfehler                            | ErroreArrotondamentoDaEuro                                           |
| EuroToRoundError                  | InEuroRundungsfehler                             | ErroreAArrotEuro                                                     |
| Fact                              | Fakultät                                         | Fatt                                                                 |
| Ancestor                          | Vorgänger                                        | Antenato                                                             |
| Children                          | Untergeordnete Elemente                          | ElementiSecondari                                                    |
| Depth                             | Tiefe                                            | Profondità                                                           |
| Descendants                       | Nachfolger                                       | Discendenti                                                          |
| IsLeaf                            | IstBlattelement                                  | ÈFoglia                                                              |
| Key                               | Schlüssel                                        | Chiave                                                               |
| Lag                               | Abstand                                          | Lag                                                                  |
| Parent                            | übergeordnetes                                   | ElementoPrincipale                                                   |
| Siblings                          | Gleichgeordnete                                  | ElementiDiPariLivello                                                |
| And                               | Und                                              | E                                                                    |
| Or                                | Oder                                             | Or                                                                   |
| NotOnBreak                        | Nicht                                            | Non                                                                  |
| Between                           | Zwischen                                         | Tra                                                                  |
| InList                            | InListe                                          | InElenco                                                             |
| All                               | Alle                                             | Tutto                                                                |
| NotOnBreak                        | NichtInGruppenwechsel                            | NonSuInterruzione                                                    |
| Row/Col                           | Zeile/Spalte                                     | Riga/Col                                                             |
| Where                             | Wo                                               | Dove                                                                 |
| Bottom/Top                        | Letzter/Erster                                   | Ultimi/Primi                                                         |
| Break                             | Gruppenwechsel                                   | Interruzione                                                         |
| IncludeEmpty                      | EinschließlichLeer                               | IncludiVuoto                                                         |
| Linear                            | Linear                                           | Lineare                                                              |
| ForAll                            | FürAlle                                          | PerTutto                                                             |
| Range                             | Bereichsoperator                                 | Intervallo                                                           |
| Block                             | Block                                            | Blocco                                                               |
| Body                              | Körper                                           | Corpo                                                                |
| Break                             |                                                  |                                                                      |
| Report                            | Bericht                                          | Report                                                               |
| Section                           | Sektion                                          | Sezione                                                              |
+-----------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Could you provide your source of documentation and source code? I would like to do this to portuguese.

Comment: I started from this https://help.sap.com/doc/businessobject_product_guides_sbo42_en_sbo42sp2_ffc_user_guide_en_pdf/4.2.2/en-US/sbo42sp2_ffc_user_guide_en.pdf and merged with a Python script the index with this https://help.sap.com/doc/businessobject_product_guides_sbo42_de_sbo42sp2_ffc_user_guide_de_pdf/4.2.2/de-DE/sbo42sp2_ffc_user_guide_de.pdf and other languages but it seems not to be published in Portuguese, so I can't imagine how to make the same dictionary for your language.